# Get Value from URL - GET Request

Tags: php, http, get

Hello I'm trying to get specific values out of my url that looks like this:

```
http://test.com/search.php?go&s=20&cacheKey=-5d36c171:14b930086c4:-561&cacheLocation=10.186.170.204:7300&customerSessionId=0ABAAACC-36C1-7191-4B92-30086C490817
```

What I have tried is e.g this:

```
$url .= '&cacheKey=' . strval($_GET['$cacheKey']);
```

But the value is not parsed correctly - What am I doing wrong ?

When I var_dump the $_GET I get the array out with all the values:

```
array(5) { ["go"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(2) "20" ["cacheKey"]=> string(26) "-5d36c171:14b930086c4:-561" ["cacheLocation"]=> string(19) "10.186.170.204:7300" ["customerSessionId"]=> string(36) "0ABAAACC-36C1-7191-4B92-30086C490817" }
```

Comment: _But the value is not parsed correctly_???

Comment: you have all the values form your link in the $_GET variable... what's wrong with this?

Comment: So.. what exactly is the problem? Seems fine to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
$url .= '&cacheKey=' . strval($_GET['cacheKey']);
```

Note the missing `$` in the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Remove $ from CacheKey.

$CacheKey is different from CacheKey.